# How to create a nested object for a given parent id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

Let's I have a parent object called `Parent` and nested object called `Kid`.

**parent.rb:**

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :kids, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

**kid.rb:**

```
class Kid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I have a parent object with **id 5**, for which I want to create a `Kid` object.

How would ruby expression look like when explicitly specify its parent object ID?
The following expression that comes to my mind at first not working:

```
5.kids.create(Name: "John)
```

Comment: Is `Parent` an `ActiveRecord` model? Is `Kid == Child`?

Comment: Yes. I will update my post with that information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways doing this

### The faster but not so safe way

```
Kid.create(parent_id: 5, name: "John")
```

This will raise an error if there's no `parent` with id = 5 in the database.

### The slower but safer way

```
Parent.find_by(id: 5)&.kids&.create(name: "John")
```

This executes 2 SQL statements, fetch the parent (id = 5), and insert a kid.

If the parent can't be found, the kid won't be created.

Comment: _"This will raise an error if there's no parent with id = 5 in the database"_ – it will just insert a new row into the `kids` table without checking the `parents` table. You need `validates :parent, presence: true` in the `Kid` class to check for the existence of the parent record but that results in another query (of course).

Comment: Not if `parent_id` is a foreign key.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I haven't worked with SQL for a while and my ActiveRecord knowledge is a bit rusty. Does Rails add foreign keys by default now?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot since which version, but at this time when you generate a model with `rails g model Foo bar:references`, the `foreign_key: true` is automatically added to the migration file.